# How to do self join in hibernate query

Tags: hibernate, hql, hibernate-criteria

I have following SQL query. How to map this to hibernate query ? '(' seems causing issue. Is this possible with Criteria Query ?

```
   select id from 
    (select prev.id from my_table prev where date = :prevDate) P
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (select curr.id from my_table curr where date = :currDate) C
    ON P.id = C.id
    where C.id is null
```

Comment: these links might help, http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-self-join-annotations-one-to-many-mapping/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31668522/hibernate-self-join-confusion

Comment: Viral's blog talks about relations in entity where we are actually have kind of self join.